# Как зная информацию из 1 столбца получить информацию из второго в той же строке sqlite python

Tags: python, sqlite, бот, aiogram, sqlite3

[image]

в общем есть таблица со столбцами name и id как зная name узнать id в той же строке?
пишу код для бота на aiogram (python)

Comment: select id from thetable where name="value"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cur.execute('SELECT id FROM video WHERE name = ?', (name, )).fetchone()
```

запятая после **name** обязательна, т.к sqlite принимает кортеж.

Comment: а как сделать что-то типа такого но рабочего:SELECT id FROM video WHERE name = ? ser=? siz=?

Comment: cur.execute('SELECT 'id' FROM video WHERE 'name' = ? AND 'ser'=? AND 'siz'=?', (name, ser, siz, )). Порядок важен